# Как скрыть/показать Floating Action Button при движении пальца вверх или вниз?

Tags: android

Мне необходимо скрывать FAB только в том случае если пользователь делает движение пальцем вверх и показывать когда пользователь делает движение пальцем вниз. Как это сделать?

Comment: Какие пути решения вы уже опробовали?

Comment: Я пытался сделать как описано по ссылке, там описано как связать FAB с RecyclerView, но проблема заключается в том, что если список в RecyclerView пустой, то FAB не скрывается при движении пальцем, ну а мне необходимо чтобы он скрывался/показывался в независимости от того пустой список в RecyclerView или нет  - http://thetechnocafe.com/how-to-hide-floating-action-button-on-when-scrolling-in-recycler-view/

Answer (score 2):

Я решил эту задачу с помощью слушателя OnTouchListener. Этот слушатель даёт нам объект MotionEvent, благодаря которому можно определить, когда пользователь сделал первое касание и последнее. Таким образом я нашел координаты двух точек и как выяснилось, что если первая точка больше второй, то необходимо спрятать FAB, иначе показать

```
public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {
    switch (event.getAction()) {
        case MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN:
            touchDown = event.getY(); // первое касание
            break;
        case MotionEvent.ACTION_UP:
            touchUp = event.getY(); // последнее касание
            break;
    }

    if (touchDown > touchUp) {
        fab.hide();
    } else {
        fab.show();
    }

    return false;
```

}

Comment: Плохой подход. Протестируй получше, по всему экрану, и изменяй длину касания пальца. Заметишь интерестный баг)

Comment: Да, пожалуй, я соглашусь. Решение не идеальное

Comment: Посмотри в гугле там были примеры. Тобишь какая то реализация дает  тебе возможнсоть найти 1 и последний элемент в списке который отображаются на экране. Вот найдешгь эти 2 значения и без проблем все решиться

Answer (score 1):

Устанавливаешь слушатель на RecyclerView.
Вызываешь

> ```
> FloatingActionButton mFab;
> mFab.hide();
> mFab.show();
> ```

Также делай проверку если список в самом вверху то показывай кнопку, если 1 элемент пропал ( от логики задачи зависит  ) то скрывай кнопку

Comment: Хорошее решение, но дело в том что если RecyclerView будет пустым, тогда кнопка не будет пропадать

Comment: Почему не будет будет. Надо проверку делать. на пустой массив адаптера. если он равен 0 то hide

Comment: Может быть, вы могли бы полностью код здесь разместить, а то я не совсем понимаю, что к чему :)